# Group of fields inside dropdown-menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I want to make a group of hidden fields inside a dropdown menu:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Export
    <b class="caret bottom-up"></b>
  </a>  
  <ul class="dropdown-menu bottom-up pull-right">  
    <li><a id="downloadJsonButton">Link1</a></li>
    <div id="downloadFormFilesDiv">
      <li class="divider"></li>  
      <li><a id="downloadXformsButton">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a id="downloadXmlButton">Link3</a><br /></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</li>
```

However, links inside div element looks differently than those which are outside it. I want to make them look the same (links: 2 and 3 should look like link1). How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Please include your CSS

Comment: Never mind i got it, share css

Comment: I'm using bootstrap and I haven't modified the css files.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li{
width: 300px;
height: 70px;
background: #000;
color: white;
}
```

Now the menu is look the same to link content and to none content.

Try delete the div between `<li>` to `<li>`, you got iligal use with him.
Hope i helped..